# AdMob In Preferences on ICS

Tags: java, android, admob, preferences

I have a very odd behaviour in my app's Preferences screen where AdMob ads reside: The ads are shown only when the screen is in landscape mode.

The AdActivity activity is declared in the manifest as follows:

The preferences are loaded with this.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); in onCreate.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The actual issue is the padding in the Preferences screen on ICS: Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <432, 1073741823>

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a margin/padding on your main layout?  If so, you will need to remove it.  The AdMob ad generally needs the entire screen (320dp width) to display an ad in portrait mode.

The Galaxy Nexus has 360dp width, so it is an exception to the "needs the entire screen" rule, but based on the space numbers you provided, you aren't running on a Galaxy Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `android:layout_width="320dp"` in your layout.

Example:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_banner"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        ads:adUnitId="your_id"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```